# I can't use the text from my Entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

There is something in my code that isn't letting me use the text from my Entry widget. I want to use the text a user will enter in my Entry widget, which i've called "textentry", in another part of my code but it doesn't seem to be storing it in a way i can use. In this example i'm just trying to print what is entered into the terminal.

I can get it to print if i uncomment the "print(textentry.get())" in my function.

As it is now i get ".!entry" printed in the terminal. i'm not sure I follow that output either.

I feel like it's probably something simple but i've been struggling a while and many different approaches but still not success.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def click():
    textentry.get()
#    print(textentry.get())
    Text_input_window.destroy()

Text_input_window= Tk()
Label (Text_input_window,text="Enter search word:", bg="black", fg="white").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
textentry = tk.Entry(Text_input_window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
Button(Text_input_window, text="SUBMIT", width=6, command=click).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
Text_input_window.mainloop()

print(textentry)
```

Comment: I think you will find a solution if you try to answer what `textentry.get()` does.

Comment: I'm not sure i really figured out the get method, but i got it to do what i wanted by adding the "textvariable" option to the Entry widget and then whatever variable i set that equal to i can use the .get() on:        
Entry(Text_input_window, textvariable=search_string, width=20, bg="white").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)                                                                                                        
and then i use "search_string.get()"

Comment: You see, `get()` is a function, it returns a value. Usually you would want to capture the returned value and save it into some variable. Like `somestring = textentry.get()` , but you also have to make sure that this variable is not local to click() method, so you have to declare it outside of it as `somestring = ''` . And then you can use it, for example `print(somestring)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

Text_input_window = Tk()
textentry = StringVar()

def click():
    global textentry
    textentry = textentry_ent.get()
#    print(textentry.get())
    Text_input_window.destroy()
Label(Text_input_window, text="Enter search word:",
      bg="black", fg="white").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
textentry_ent = tk.Entry(Text_input_window, textvariable=textentry,width=20, bg="white")
textentry_ent.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
Button(Text_input_window, text="SUBMIT", width=6,
       command=click).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

Text_input_window.mainloop()

print(textentry)
```